# PySpark Pushing down timestamp filter

Tags: apache-spark

I'm using PySpark version 2.4 to read some tables using jdbc with a Postgres driver.

```
    df = spark.read.jdbc(url=data_base_url, table="tablename", properties=properties)
```

One column is a timestamp column and I want to filter it like this:

```
    df_new_data = df.where(df.ts > last_datetime )
```

This way the filter is pushed down as a SQL query but the datetime format
is not right. So I tried this approach

```
    df_new_data = df.where(df.ts > F.date_format( F.lit(last_datetime), "y-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss.SSS") )
```

but then the filter is no pushed down anymore.

Can someone clarify why this is the case ?

Answer (score 1):

While loading the data from a Database table, if you want to push down queries to database and get few result rows, instead of providing the 'table', you can provide the 'Query' and return just the result as a DataFrame. This way, we can leverage database engine to process the query and return only the results to Spark.

The table parameter identifies the JDBC table to read. **You can use anything that is valid in a SQL query FROM clause**. Note that alias is mandatory to be provided in query.

```
pushdown_query = "(select * from employees where emp_no < 10008) emp_alias"
df = spark.read.jdbc(url=jdbcUrl, table=pushdown_query, properties=connectionProperties)
df.show()
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer! 
This is how I do it now and it also works as expected. 
But I wanted to avoid creating a new jdbc connections every time I query a table, as this would be the case here as far as I understand it. I'm running this quite often per second and sometimes creating a connection can be more expensive than actually querying the data.

Also I don't see any option to change the internal datetime formate, which maybe would be another solution.

Comment: Agree, this would create new connection every time.